# EF core with Cosmos DB seems not support distinct().count(). Is there any approach to do a distinct count?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-cosmosdb

I find that cosmos DB support get a distinct count using SQL like

```
select value count(1) from (SELECT distinct c.StoreId FROM c)
```

But with EF core, `context.Model.FromSqlRaw(@join)` does not support return a Raw type instead of dbset model. Is it possible to return a custom raw type in ef core?

Answer (score 0):

Queries with an aggregate system function and a subquery with DISTINCT are only supported in specific SDK versions. For example, queries with the following shape are only supported in the below specific SDK versions:

SELECT COUNT(1) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT f.lastName FROM f)

[image]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/sql-query-keywords